# Gorm Find result to interface

Tags: go, reflection, go-gorm

I am trying to build a generic CrudRepository struct using **Gorm** for my api.
I know generics are coming to GoLang in version 2 but I try to build this lib using reflection or any other lib.

In my CrudRepository:

```golang
func (repository *BaseRepository) find(result interface{}, pageSize int, page int) error {
  if page < 1 {
    return errors.ExceedsMinimumInt("page", "", 0, true, nil)
  }

  offset := (page - 1) * pageSize

  ent := reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(result))

  repository.db = repository.db.Limit(pageSize).Offset(offset)
  err := repository.db.Find(&ent).Error

  result = ent

  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return nil
}
```

And calling this method sth like:

```golang
func List(){
  var entityList []MyEntity
  find(entityList, 1, 10)
}
```

I think, I cannot pass any interface reference into **Gorm.db.Find()** method
Is there any other way to succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pointer of a slice as input argument of *custom* `find` method.

```
func (repository *BaseRepository) find(result interface{}, pageSize int, page int) error {
    if page < 1 {
      return errors.ExceedsMinimumInt("page", "", 0, true, nil)
    }

    if reflect.TypeOf(result).Kind() != reflect.Slice {  check ❗️
        return errors.New("`result` is not a slice")
    }

    offset := (page - 1) * pageSize

    db = db.Limit(pageSize).Offset(offset)
    
    if err := db.Find(result).Error; err  != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

usage

```
var entityList []MyEntity
err := find(&entityList, 10, 1)
```

Also you have to check input argument (`result`), because `db.Find` isn't fit to find single strut  ([Retrieving a single object](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-a-single-object))

> If you want to avoid the ErrRecordNotFound error, you could use Find
> like db.Limit(1).Find(&user), the Find method accepts both struct and
> slice data

For example (`Book` table is empty):

```
b := Book{}
rowsAffectedQuantity := db.Find(&b).RowsAffected //  0
err = db.Find(&b).Error //  nil
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I made mistake with pointers and references.